# Python Mouse Pointer Movement without Using External Libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pointer move, no library using Python. I am getting an error.

Trying to get the pointer to move, and return to original position on Python 3.9 and its giving me an error at `new_x`.

Spec is we cannot import libraries, or use PowerShell, just what is there already.

Why won't this run?

```py
import ctypes
import time

MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001
MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000

target_x = 500
target_y = 500

movement_amount = 50

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

screen_width = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
screen_height = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

while True:
    original_x, original_y = ctypes.c_long(), ctypes.c_long()
    user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(original_x), ctypes.byref(original_y))

    
    new_x = target_x + movement_amount
    new_y = target_y + movement_amount

    
    absolute_x = int(new_x / screen_width * 65535)
    absolute_y = int(new_y / screen_height * 65535)

    
    user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, absolute_x, absolute_y, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(1)  # Wait for a brief moment

    
    user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, int(original_x.value / screen_width * 65535), int(original_y.value / screen_height * 65535), 0, 0)
    
    
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Your code works for me. I had  `python 3.9.13` laying around so, I used that.

Comment: Thanks very much for trying it. Must be a me issue. Sent to friend an hour ago and it works on his as well.